# Loop over directory with XTools tool

Tags: arcpy, loop, xtools-pro

I'm trying to loop through a directory of shp files with an XTool Pro tool via arcpy. My script successfully performs the operation on the first shp file, but then fails on the rest with a 000584 error "*Implementation of this Tool's Validate is invalid"* Here is my script:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Data_State\MT\temp"
arcpy.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files (x86)/DataEast/XTools Pro/Toolbox/XTools Pro.tbx")
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
   arcpy.XToolsGP_AddXYZ_xtp(fc,"X longitude;Y latitude","CENTER","GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS84',SPHEROID['WGS84',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]","NONE")
```

Does anyone know why the tool is unable to loop through the files?

---

Updated script and I'm still having the same issue

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Data_State\MT\temp"
arcpy.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files (x86)/DataEast/XTools Pro/Toolbox/XTools Pro.tbx")
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    if fc.endswith(".shp"):
        try:
            print(fc)
            arcpy.RepairGeometry_management(fc)
            print(fc + " Parcels Repaired")

        except:
            print(fc + " repair failed.")
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    if fc.endswith(".shp")
        try:
            arcpy.XToolsGP_AddXYZ_xtp(fc,"X longitude;Y latitude","CENTER","GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS84',SPHEROID['WGS84',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]","NONE")
        except:
            print(fc + " failed.")
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you have put any sort of filter in for type of feature classes.  As it cycles through the feature classes, it may be running across a feature type that this tool cannot handle, thus causing a validation error.

Comment: All of the shp files in the directory are polygons, so I don't think that's it. I added an if fc.endswith(".shp"): to the script and I'm still having the same issue. I'll edit my code to reflect this

Comment: Are all of the polygons valid?  Have you checked for bad geometries in the layers?  You say the operation fails on the rest with that error.  Is it possible it is simply failing on the next one alphabetically and not on all the rest?  You might try to specifically list another feature class and see if the function works.  This might point to an issue with just the 2nd feature class in the list.

Comment: I added arcpy.RepairGeometry_management(fc) and still getting the same results

Comment: Are you trying to run this with 32bit or 64bit arcpy?  Xtools won't run in 64bit.

Comment: I'm running it on 32bit

Comment: Does the script run if you remove all Parameters except fc? I can't tell which params are required.

Comment: @morgan I can confirm I get the exact same error.  I created 5 polygon shapefiles and added a handful of features to each.  I could successfully run the tool manually in ArcMap, but when trying in arcpy it worked on the first then failed with the same error when trying the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same error when trying to loop through feature classes to Add X,Y,Z to features.  The ArcGIS Error 000584 message suggests it's a third party tool error, so XTools Pro will need to fix it.

However, it appears that XTools Pro also has a "batch" tool for the `Add X,Y,Z Coordinates` tool, called `arcpy.XToolsGpAddCoordsBatch_xtp` which will allow you to add to a batch of feature classes (as you're doing) - Maybe this is their workaround to the above error.

```py
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Data_State\MT\temp"
arcpy.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files (x86)/DataEast/XTools Pro/Toolbox/XTools Pro.tbx")

fcList = ";".join(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*.shp"))

arcpy.XToolsGpAddCoordsBatch_xtp(fcList, "CENTER", "CENTER", "CENTER", "Longitude", "Latitude", "", "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS84',SPHEROID['WGS84',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]", "NONE")
```

The line `fcList = ";".join(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*.shp"))` is because the tool accepts a semicolon (`;`) separated string of feature classes, not a list.

Comment: Ah, perfect! I was trying to batch tool also but wasn't adding the semicolon to my list so it was failing. Your method works perfectly, thank you for the help!